# Is singleton popolar in real time trading system wcf wpf

Tags: wpf, wcf, singleton

Suppose I have a wcf service.

If I need to design it as a singleton pattern, just need it put is like:
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single]?

Is this design pattern popular in real-time stock trading system using wcf wpf?

Comment: Yes, that is the way you can implement a singleton in a WCF operation

Comment: so this pattern is popular in real time trading system? why the singleton is popular? thx

Comment: I don't know if it is popular, actually, I don't remember any of services I've developed using singleton instance option. Even if you use shared resources, that is a common scenario for a singleton, you can do it thread safe. You can read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc681240%28VS.100%29.aspx